# SQL query checking for a table row with certain email adres fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=$email")
or die(mysql_error());
```

In this case $email is filled with "info@frankkluytmans.nl". The error I get when this query gets executed is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@frankkluytmans.nl' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things..

1. Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated!
2. Sanitize the input. In your example, you should quote `$email` because it's a literal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the email variable.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

You should know however, that the "mysql_" range of PHP functions are soon going to be deprecated and should be replaced with the mysqli API.  A quick sample showing how to use it can be found at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples

Comment: I have added to my original comment to show the deprecation of mysql_*.  However, my original response was not promoting the use of mysql_query.  It was simply answering his question about a syntax problem.  There are several valid reasons why he may have been using that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'")
```

quote it.

Also, the regular PHP mysql functions will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Take a look at [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), [pdo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Promoting the use of mysql_*? Read the last sentences of my answer again.

Comment: mysql functions are already deprecated, they will be removed as of php 5.5

Comment: You're wrong. According to `php.net` they will be removed in the feature. Quote: `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.`

Comment: Good catch; my bad. They're still deprecated in my book since php 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

You need to have quotes around the variable and its good practice to not have variables inside your string.

You might want to check out alternatives to MySQL_ though as its now deprecated.  Try [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put single quotes around $email

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'")
```

Answer (score 0):

for frankkluytmans.nl conflict with syntax for mysql query i.e tablename.columnname

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'")
```

Comment: and when their database gets injected...?

Comment: @RobW must be promoted to use mysqli but there is a reality and big challenge to convert old website to use mysqli...

Comment: If they're using these types of queries, where they're already either unprepared or sanitized, then their site is already at risk; mitigating the risk now helps reduce the chance of injection later. In the end, it'll end up needing to be done anyways y'know?

Answer (score -1):

Please change your query.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email"'");
```